# Finding the inverse of this R-module homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Define the function $\phi :\text{End}_R(nM)\to M_n\text{(End}_R(M))$ by the following map:

$$(\phi(\sigma))_{jk}=\pi_j\circ\sigma\circ\iota_k$$

Where $\pi_j$ and $\iota_k$ are the natural injection for the ($j,k$) entry of the matrix. Can someone help me defining the inverse mapping?

Comment: By $nM$ you mean a direct sum of $n$ copies of $M$ right?

Comment: Right, sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 1):

Let $M_n({\rm End}_R(M))$ act on vectors in $M^{\oplus n}$ the same way we usually have matrices act on vectors...